# Removing whitespace in SAX Parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I have the following XML file.Why whitespaces are coming in `characters()` even after applying validation

```
<Employee>
<Name>
James
</Name>
<Id>
11
</Id>
</Employee>
```

I am trying to display text in between the tags.

```
 public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    boolean isName = false;
    boolean isId = false;

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2) throws SAXException {
        if (isName) {
            System.out.println(new String(arg0, arg1, arg2));
            isName = false;
        }
        if (isId) {
            System.out.println(new String(arg0, arg1, arg2));
            isId = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
            Attributes arg3) throws SAXException {          
        if (arg2.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {
            isName = true;
        }
        if (arg2.equalsIgnoreCase("Id")) {
            isId = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Desired Ouput:

```
James
11
```

Actual Output:

```
James

11
```

Why spaces ares coming in output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a [validating parser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/validation.html) it will report the ignorable whitespace via `ignorableWhitespace()` method instead of `characters().`

Otherwise the parser is perfectly entitled to give you whitespace via `characters().` See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters(char[],%20int,%20int)).

Comment: It will not give me text in between the tags.

Comment: @Sanjana I do not understand your comment. Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

The actual string value of the text node that is a child of the `<Name>` tag is

```
\nJames\n
```

Likewise, the string value of the text node in the `<Id>` is

```
\n11\n
```

where `\n` represents a newline character.  None of the newlines are ignorable whitespace. If you want to remove them you must do it yourself, in your Java code.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the whitespace removed for you if you put the XML through a schema (XSD) validator and declare the types of Name and Id with a type that collapses all whitespace, e.g. type xs:token. A DTD validator will never do this for text nodes (only for attribute nodes).